# Prove that if $f$ is analytic and bounded at $\{{z:0<|z|< \infty}\}$, then it is a constant function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $f$ is analytic and bounded at $\{{z:0<|z|< \infty}\}$, then it is a constant function.

Well, all could I say in this case that if it turns out to be constant in the answer, then $f$ must have been with removable singularity point at $z=0$, so by defining $f$ to be with a certain value there, we can get an analytic function everywhere and bounded, so by Liouville theorem , we can say that its constant.
but then I thought, how would I be sure that this is the case?
any hints?

Comment: Is an analytic function bounded near a nonremovable singularity?

Comment: nice,, sounds intuitive, but is there a formalism for this? I mean I can see why its not a pole, but why would it not be an essential singularity? Its even logical to find a Laurent series arond $z=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded on $\{z\in\Bbb C:z\ne0\}$ and then you extend $f$ to $\Bbb C$ then $f$ is still bounded: $|f(z)|\le\max(|f(0|),M)$
where $M$ is a bound for $|f(z)|$ on $\{z\in\Bbb C:z\ne0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$g(z)= zf(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, hence can be extended to $\Bbb C$. If $g(0)\ne 0$, then $f(z)=\frac {g(z)}z$ is not bounded near $0$, hence $g(0)=0$. But then $g(z)=zh(z)$ for some entire $h$ - which is the same as $f$ and Liouville applies.

Comment: okay, but why it cant have an essential singularity?

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani If $f(z)$ is analytic and bounded on $0 < |z| < r$ then $h(z) = z^2 f(z)$ is holomorphic and hence analytic on $|z| < r$. Thus at $z=0$, $h(z)$ has a zero of order $n$ and $f(z)$ a zero of order $n-2 \ge 0$ (if $n< 2$ then $f(z)$ wasn't bounded) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem